# How to Set Parent Panel Alignment of The Control Programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

***Background:***

I have created a helper method to set properties of each `TextBlock`as per its adjacent `TextBox` for some scenarios in my application. In this method I already have the `TextBlock` object, the `TextBox` object and the parent object (it's always `RelativePanel` in my case).
The `RelativePanel` in my views always contain only `TextBox` & `TextBlock`.

```
// Helper Method
public static void SetPropertiesOfEachTextBlock(IList<TextBox> boxes)
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in boxes)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(textBox) as RelativePanel;
        foreach(var element in parent.Children)
        {
            if(element is TextBlock)
            {
                TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)element;
                textBlock.FontSize = textBox.FontSize;
                textBlock.Margin = textBox.Margin;
                textBlock.FontWeight = textBox.FontWeight;
                textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                // Here I need to set alignment to the adjacent TextBox by the RelativePanel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Relative Panel Sample:

```
         <RelativePanel>
            <TextBox Name="UserName"/>
            <TextBlock RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="UserName" />
        </RelativePanel>
```

***Question:***

How can I set the following property of `TextBlock` programmatically:

```
RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="UserName"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AlignLeft` is an *Attached Property* and can be found on `RelativePanel` itself. You set them like this:

```
RelativePanel.SetAlignLeftWith(element, UserName);
```

You can read the docs on the property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_RelativePanel_SetAlignLeftWithPanel_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_System_object_):

**Edit:** fixed syntax error based on comment

Comment: This setter is static .. this works for me: `RelativePanel.SetAlignLeftWith(textBlock, textBox);`